# Authenticate method in django returns None

Tags: python, django, django-models

It is the first time I do a project in Django. As a first step, I am creating methods to sign-up and sign-in users.

The sign-up works well. However, after registering an user, I try to sign-in without success.

My *models.py* file is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
        # set_password will handle the password before saving it in the database
        # It hash the password before saving it
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)

    
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "users"
```

and the sign-in method in *views.py* is the following one:

```
def signin(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")

        # Authenticate the user
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        # If it is not None - user exists and right credentials
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            fname = user.first_name
            return render(request, "authentication/index.html", {'fname': fname})
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Bad credentials")
            return redirect("home")

    return render(request, "authentication/signin.html")
```

Also, this is my 'sign up' function:

```
def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        fname = request.POST.get("fname")
        lname = request.POST.get("lname")
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        password2 = request.POST.get("password2") 

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username = username, fname 
        = fname, lname = lname, email=email, password=password)
        myuser.first_name = fname
        myuser.last_name = lname
        myuser.is_active = False
        myuser.save()

        # redirect to login
        return redirect("signin")

    return render(request, "authentication/signup.html")
```

Since I am using a custom User table in my database, I'll share also my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path
from Memovies.info import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

EMAIL_USE_TLS = EMAIL_USE_TLS
EMAIL_HOST = EMAIL_HOST
EMAIL_HOST_USER = EMAIL_HOST_USER
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD
EMAIL_PORT = EMAIL_PORT

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "authentication",
    "catalog",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "Memovies.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": ["templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "Memovies.wsgi.application"


AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'

#Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"
```

- Debugging it, I have realized that the method *authenticate* is returning me a None. Do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Simple question, but are you sure you are passing the correct data to `authenticate()`?

Comment: Hello @ViaTech. Thanks your the question! Yes... I checked that the username and password I'm passing to the function are the same values of the user I have saved in my database :(

Comment: Can we see your `register` view too? Your authentication looks fine, the fact that `authenticate()` returns `None` shows that the correct credentials are not being used: "If the credentials aren’t valid for any backend or if a backend raises PermissionDenied, it returns None". Just for completeness, please also post your whole `settings.py` and your Auth Backend used from `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [...]` (if you are using a custom auth backend)

Comment: Hello @ViaTech, I have edited the post with my method to register users and my settings.py... To be fair, I read about the custom auth backend, but I think I am not understanding well that concept. Thanks!